# using dev_queue_xmit to send sk_buff

Tags: linux, networking

I wonder if my sk_buff's mac_header, transport_header is not correct, can I send this packet successfully through dev_queue_xmit()?

If I want to push some data before the link layer's data, how to do it?

Answer (score 3):

Yes you can. Usually I do the following:

1) use `netdev_alloc_skb()` to allocate the buffer and to avoid alignment headaches

2) use `skb_reserve()` for space equal to (ethhdr + iphdr + tcphdr (or other transport header))

3) use `skb_put()` before filling in the payload (the data payload following the transport header)

4) use `skb_push()` before filling in the transport header

5) use `skb_reset_transport_header()` to mark the transport header

6) use `skb_push()` before filling in the network header

7) use `skb_reset_network_header()` to mark the ip header

8) use `skb_push()` before filling in the eth header

9) use `skb_reset_mac_header()` to mark the eth header

10) use `dev_queue_xmit` to send the packet

Answer (score 0):

1. Why not? In most cases you can send almost everything - even 1 byte. It depends on the driver.
2. You may use skb_push() procedure to do it.